# How to find a file and copy its directory?

Tags: command-line, find, cp, file-copy

I use the following command to find a file and copy it somewhere else,

```
find /search/ -name file.txt -exec cp -Rp {} /destination \;
```

How can I copy all files and subdirectories in the parent directory of `file.txt`?

**Example,**

```
/search/test/sub
/search/test/sub2
/search/test/file.txt
/search/test/file.doc
```

They should be copied as

```
/destination/sub
/destination/sub2
/destination/file.txt
/destination/file.doc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `-execdir` (not a standard predicate, but often implemented), the given utility would execute in the directory where the file was found.

This means that you could do

```
find /search -name file.txt -execdir cp -Rp . /destination \;
```

Without `-execdir`:

```
find /search -name file.txt -exec sh -c 'cp -Rp "${1%/*}/." /destination' sh {} \;
```

or,

```
find /search -name file.txt -exec sh -c 'cd "${1%/*}" && cp -Rp . /destination' sh {} \;
```

These last two variations execute a short in-line script for each found file.  The script takes the pathname of the file as its first argument (in `$1`), and strips the filename off of the pathname using `${1%/*}` (a standard parameter substitution).  Then it applies the same `cp` command as in the first variation with `-execdir`.

The code that does the `cd` emulates a bit more faithfully what the `-execdir` variation at the top actually does, while the middle variation bypasses changing the directory by referring to `.` in the source directory at the end of the path instead.